# Error occures while creating new app for react by create-react-app using cmd

Tags: reactjs, npm

See the issue on reactjs:

[image: Image source click here to see the issue on reactjs]

here you can see what's the issue please help me to resolve this

```
appdata -> roaming -> npm ->
```

[image: click to get folder appdata]

->  folder roaming

[image: click to getoaming folder roaming]

-> then npm folder

[image: then npm folder npm folder]

-> inside npm folder

[image: inside npm folder]

The issue is:

```
D:\ashish>create-react-app shoppingcart-ashish

Creating a new React app in D:\ashish\shoppingcart-ashish.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-02T08_46_41_747Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting shoppingcart-ashish/ from D:\ashish
Done.
```

Comment: Please add a picture of the log.

Comment: Image source click here to see the issue od reactjs => have to seen this in my code, please click on it and you will get the image

Comment: On your image, there is a mention of the npm log which is inside your AppData folder. Please post a picture of that.

Comment: please check again

Answer (score 1):

I have re-install the npm as latest ( 16.0.0. and remove all the files from previous node js and npm files too..

from C:\Users\Ashish\AppData\Roaming\npm

and in my case AppData is hidden and now working fine
Thank you!